# How do I create and elimate a carousel based on media queries?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, media-queries, caroufredsel

I have a row of images that are supposed to appear on my page unless the window is 320px or below. If the window is 320px or below then I have images being placed in a carousel. The problem I am having is that I am trying to figure out how to get rid of the carousel when the window is more 320px. So the scenario would be on a mobile device when a user changes he orientation from portrait to horizontal I want the images to be in a carousel when the device is portrait and in a row when landscape. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="carousel">
<img src="endlessSummer_154x176.jpg">
<img src="visa_154x176_new.jpg">
<img src="lifestyle_240x176_new_v2.jpg">
<img src="nfl_cy_410x176_new.jpg">
</div>

$(window).resize(function(){    
        if ( $(".carousel").css("width") === "320px") {
            $(".carousel").carouFredSel();
        }else{
            $('.carousel').destroy();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, all you need to do is call the trigger event in order to fire the destroy

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ( $(".carousel").css("width") === "320px") {
        $(".carousel").carouFredSel();
    }else{
        $('.carousel').trigger("destroy", true);
    }
});
```

Or you can just use trigger("destroy") if you don't care about returning things to their original order.

Comment: do you know if there's anything you can do to maintain the order after destroy?